# How to add custom GUI component to ToolBox

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I have downloaded [objectListView](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/index.html) but do not know how to add the component to ToolBox, and so that I could drag it to my application. Anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply follow these steps:

1. In the Toolbox, right click to select `Add Tab`.
2. Provide appropriate name to that Tab.
3. Right click in the new tab and select `Choose Items...`
4. Browse the DLL and all the components will be listed in the new Tab.

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify: **in the Choose Items dialog, make sure you have the ".NET Framework Components" selected**. For some reason I started in the "COM Components" tab myself, and while you can click the Browse button there as well, you will get a message that there are no controls in the dll.